# Replace of N/A as zero in excel

Tags: excel

I have a row having some values from A1 to A3. I have

```
100
30
#N/A
```

I tried

```
=Average(A1:A3)
```

But since I have value as #N/A am not able get the avg of 3 values. I want to treat #N/A as 0 and get the avg

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/14754654/227646

Comment: Selecting the cell with N/A, what does it say in the function box? Also N/A as plain text? Or is it the result of another function?

Comment: You can add a new column that will normalize the number :


=IF(ISERROR(cell),0,cell)


and then run the sum function on it

Comment: You've already asked this question, practically: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43227344/excel-replacement-values-for-n-a?rq=1

Comment: `=AVERAGE(IFNA(A1:A3,0)) [ctrl-shift-enter]`

Comment: @jsheeran please add that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array formula for this:

`=AVERAGE(IFNA(A1:A3,0))` (Ctrl-Shift-Enter)

Comment: I typed abpve formula and getting 0 though I have some values.what you mean by [ctrl-shift-enter] here

Comment: Because it's an array formula you have to press Ctrl-Shift-Enter to input it, instead of just Enter as you'd do for a normal formula.

Comment: ... or as a standard (i.e. non-array) formula as`=AGGREGATE(1, 6, A1:A3)`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, wasn't aware of `AGGREGATE()`. However, it doesn't solve OP's problem because it ignores N/A values rather than treating them as 0.